# DefaultView.Sort is resetting

Tags: c#, data-binding, datatable, dataset, bindingsource

I need help with this code:

```
DataAdapter1.Fill(DataSet1);
DataSet1.Tables[0].DefaultView.Sort = "sortcolumn";
BindingSource1.DataSource =  DataSet1.Tables[0].DefaultView;
```

After execution, the "DataSet1.Tables[0].DefaultView.Sort" property is reset to empty string.
What might be the cause of this, and how can this be avoided?

Thanks

Edit:

The problem was that in the designer window, when I previously set the Sort property of the BindingSource to some value, and then later I deleted it, the designer was initializing it's value to an empty string, not to null, which was causing the problem.
I just deleted the initialization for the Sort property from the designer code (I suppose you can't set the value to null from the designer window).
The issue is solved.